# Не отображаются иконки в контекстном меню

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Пишу приложение на WPF создаю на `DataGrid Context menu`:

```
<DataGrid.ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu>
                    <MenuItem x:Name="Add" Click="Add_Click" Header="Добавить" >
                        <MenuItem.Icon>
                            <Image Source="pack://siteoforigin:,,,/Resources/plus.png"  />
                        </MenuItem.Icon>
                    </MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem Header="Изменить" x:Name="Edit" Click="Edit_Click">
                        <MenuItem.Icon>
                            <Image Source="pack://siteoforigin:,,,/Resources/pencil.png"  />
                        </MenuItem.Icon>
                    </MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem Header="Удалить" x:Name="Delete" Click="Delete_Click">
                        <MenuItem.Icon>
                            <Image Source="pack://siteoforigin:,,,/Resources/close.png" />
                        </MenuItem.Icon>
                    </MenuItem>
                </ContextMenu>
            </DataGrid.ContextMenu>
```

Все работает, за исключением того, что не отображаются иконки в меню. Сами иконки добавлены в файл ресурсов

Comment: Попробуйте вместо `siteoforigin` использовать `application`.

Comment: И да, из вашего вопроса непонятно, отображаются ли те же иконки вне контекстного меню?

Comment: изменил на application не отображается

Answer (score 1):

Решение проблемы:
1. В проекте ищем изображение и в его свойстве Действие при сборке выбираем Resourse.
2. Вместо siteoforigin использовать application